# Automatic synchronization tool for MS SQL Server

Tags: database, sql-server

I am looking for a specific tool which should automatically syncronizes the data between two databases present on two different servers. Whatever gets updates or inserted on the database on 1st server should automatically fill onto the database on 2nd server.

Is there any such software available ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLServer built-in replication and you can use [Replication Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms152501.aspx) to automatically Sync the databases.